# Why JQuery animation(slide) are not smooth on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I am making a slide presentation for ipad. My code is working fine in all browser chrome, safari , Mozilla etc but its little jumpy on ipad.

Here is the jquery code

```
   $("#sarah01_1").delay(1000).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

here is css code

```
   #sarah01_1{ position:absolute;
               left:20px; 
               top:115px;
               width:270;
               height:333px;
               display:none;
           }
```

Comment: Can I suggest you take a look at the Jquery UI Effects library where you can set easings for effects?

If possible, you can also do CSS animations as it takes up less memory, less amount of actions to complete an Animation, and less actual time to complete an animation. Its not 100% relative answers to your question, but ideas :)

Comment: I tried using linear easing but still same result. switching to CSS animation will take a bunch of changes as there are many such animations in my project. I think its something issue with ipads they doesn't support jquery animation properly not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed slide,blind and some other typical animation to fadeIn , animate etc. now its looking much better. Seems like iPad devices catch size is very low so the heavy animations doesn't run properly.
yeah css transition is much better idea for good performance, I will use that in future projects.